# Get managers first from table and employees later

Tags: oracle

I have a table like this

```
NAME -- MANAGER
10 -- 85
85 -- 45
45 -- 52
52 -- null
```

I want an output like this, where manager is put first in an hierarchy and then the employees

```
 NAME -- MANAGER

  52 -- null

  45 -- 52

  85 -- 45

  10 -- 85
```

Can anyone help me do it. I did inner join like below, but it didn't work

```
select * from TABLEMAIN

 inner join TABLEMAIN t2 ON TABLEMAIN.MANAGER = t2.NAME

 order by TABLEMAIN.NAME
```

Please help me arrive at a solution

Comment: Are you looking for a hierarchical scan of your data (like in the first answer) or do you want to simply order by your manager ids?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can be achieved using start with and connect by

```
WITH TABLEMAIN(NAME,MANAGER) AS
    (SELECT 10 ,85 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 85 , 45 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 45 ,52 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 52 ,null FROM dual )
----
-- End of data
----
SELECT * FROM TABLEMAIN
START WITH manager IS NULL
CONNECT BY PRIOR NAME = manager
```

Output:

```
NAME MANAGER
52  
45  52
85  45
10  85
```

Comment: SQLFiddle seems to be offline. Or is this only my problem?

Comment: @Stijn Its not hard coding, its just data preparation, actual query start after `---End of data` line.